# Problems with retrieving R^2 and F-stat following running a loop of linear regressions

Tags: r, linear-regression

So my data set is 16S rRNA counts for specific microbes based on duration of a treatment. I managed to run a loop to automatically do 1,660 linear regressions for me, and I have been able to view the p-values, but I haven't been able to get a full summary or even just call the R^2 values.

Here is the code I used for the loop: (my data has a total of 1,661 columns including the time column)

```
# number of columns
n <- 1661
pulseregfinal <- read.csv("pulseregression.csv")

time <- pulseregfinal$time



# run n regressions
my_lms <- lapply(1:n, function(x) lm(pulseregfinal[,x] ~ time, data = pulseregfinal))
```

Then I attempted to get my summaries:

```
# extract just coefficients
sapply(my_lms, coef)

summaries <- lapply(my_lms, summary)
# ...coefficents with p values:
lapply(summaries, function(x) x$coefficients[, c(1,4)])
# ...or r-squared values
sapply(summaries, function(x) c(r_sq = x$r.squared, 
                            adj_r_sq = x$adj.r.squared))
```

But I either just get a list of numbers from 1 to 1661 or I get this:

[image]

I was expecting to get a list of R^2 values and the linear regression the came from...
Any help as to what I can do to view the data as well as how to export it cleanly in such a way were I could then sort the data by p-value would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the loop to extract the `r.squares`:

```
pulseregfinal <- read.csv("pulseregression.csv")

mod <- summary(lm(as.matrix(subset(pulseregfinal,,-time)) ~ time, pulseregfinal))

sapply(mod, getElement, 'r.squared')
```

Example:

```
mod <- summary(lm(as.matrix(subset(iris,,-Species)) ~ Species, iris))
sapply(mod, getElement, 'r.squared')
Response Sepal.Length  Response Sepal.Width Response Petal.Length 
            0.6187057             0.4007828             0.9413717 
 Response Petal.Width 
            0.9288829
```